# If there is no open interval containing $p$, is $p$ a limit point?

Tags: general-topology, logic

First we begin with my understanding of the definition of a limit point. 
“$p$ is said to be a limit point of a point set $M$ if every open interval containing $p$ contains a point of $M$ distinct from $p$.“ With this definition, suppose there is no open interval containing $p’$, is $p’$ a limit point? Under this definition there’s an implication that an open interval exists, the definition can be rewritten as “If there exists an open interval containing $p$, it must contain a point of $M$ distinct from $p$.” With this restatement, since there does not exist an open interval containing $p’$ then one could argue that every open interval (if it existed) contains a point of $M$ distinct from $p’.$ With this same logic I think you could argue the opposite way as well however I’m wondering if my argument works.

Comment: Are you in the reals?  Because $(p-1, p+1)$ will definitely contain $p$.

Comment: "open interval" doesn't make sense in just any point set $M$. Maybe you misquoted.

Comment: @Randall I’m doing point set topology so at this point (no pun intended) there is no notion of addition

Comment: @KennyLau I rechecked my definition and that’s what it says

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: @KennyLau no book, we’re proving all the theorems on our own for the course. The definitions comes from the teachers notes

Comment: Then the reliability of your notes or even of the lecturer is not guaranteed.

Comment: @KennyLau what would be a proper definition?

Comment: Change "open interval" to "open set" or "neighbourhood".

Comment: To get to OP's question, if we replace "open interval" by "open set" then the question is valid.  But then we should recall that $X$ (the total space) is an open set.

Comment: OP:  to set the stage for your question, you should have a topological space $X$, some subset $M$ of $X$, and some point $p \in X$.  You then want to ask if $p$ is a limit point of $M$ if there are no open sets about $p$.  (But there is one, namely $X$.)

Comment: @Randall so no matter what space I’m in there will always be an open set that contains the point? Therefore my situation is impossible?

Comment: Correct.  By an axiom/default, $X$ itself is open.

Comment: @Randall I think that answers my question then. There’s no sense in “but what if it were possible”

Comment: Your question becomes slightly more interesting if you ask about the case where there are no **proper** open sets containing $p$ (because examples of this actually exist), but even then it's not hard to work out just by the definitions.

Comment: @Randall would you mind adding an answer reflecting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be a subset in a space $X$ and consider a point $p \in X$.  You want to ask what happens in analyzing if $p$ is a limit point of $M$ if there happens to be no open sets about $p$.  Well, that can't happen, since $X$ is open and $p \in X$.  So, as we discussed upthread in comments, your question is pointless (pun intended).

You could ponder:  what if $X$ is the *only* open set about $p$?  In other words, no proper open set surrounds $p$.  In that case, $p$ usually is a limit point of $M$.  This will be the case as long as $M$ contains something different than $p$.

An example of this occurring is to take $X=\{1, 2, 3\}$ and give it the topology 
$$
\varnothing, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, X.
$$ 
Take $p=3$ and note that $X$ is the only open set about $p$.  With $M=\{1,2\}$ we see that $p=3$ is a limit point of $M$:  the open set $X$ contains the point $1 \in M$, and $1$ is not $p$.  Since this is the only open candidate, we're done.  The same argument flies with $p=3$ being a limit point of $M'=\{1,3\}$.

But, with $M''=\{3\}$ we have trouble.  Here the unique open set about $p$, namely $X$, contains no point of $M''$ different from $p=3$.  Thus $p$ is not a limit point of $M''$.

**Exercise:**  with the same set $X$ with topology above, work out all limit points of $\{2\}$ and then $\{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**The definition** "If every open interval containing $p$ contains a point of $M$ distinct from $p$ then $p$  is said to be a limit point of a point set $M$ " is a conditional statement.

For a conditional statement the *inverse* is not true in general. However its *contrapositive* is always true.

Take $p=1$ in the set $[0,1]$ for which your definition doesn't fit into the antecedant part even.